# How to build key drivers analysis of Nps in python?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statistics, regression

I have a dataframe like this(columns are a 10 point scale)

| NPS product | time | quality | comfort |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 6 | 4 | 3 | 7 |
| 2 | 3 | 7 | 8 |

I have to found the impact of other variables on nps product. I tried with linear regression with sklearn but R2 is very low.

Im not really good in statistic, which is the best methods to measure it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

for regression your feature set or independent variables has to be at least interval scaled which means the differences in the data points has to be meaningful. In your case all the data points are in ordinal scale i.e. order is meaningful but differences are not. You can try Spearman’s Rank Correlation for ordinal data. Check this
https://towardsdatascience.com/discover-the-strength-of-monotonic-relation-850d11f72046

Else you can try ordinal regression

Comment: Thank you! Which is the package in python to build ordinal regression? I tried statsmodels but it doesn't work

Comment: actually I have not done it myself. you can try 'mord' package. One thing I should note on your objective though: to keep interpretations and operations simple you can persist with linear regression and look into the coefficient and P values of each variable. R2 is a measure of predictive power only and it does not say anything about individual variable's relation with your NPS. So a low R2 does not mean that individually time or quality is unrelated with NPS. Low R2 means that only those 3 variables can explain NPS at a very low degree

Comment: Ok thank you, so with linear regression, if the coefficient are: time 0.40, quality 0.2 and comfort 0.04, it means that time have more impact on nps product than quality and comfort at the end?if they are significant obviously

Comment: Since all your variables are unit less and have same scale, I guess you are correct